# How to prevent React-router from messing up your API url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a POST endpoint set up like so:

```
// from server.js
const photo = require('./routes/imagesRoute');

app.use("/api/photo",photo);

//imagesRoute.js
 router.route('/photos/:id') // final path will thus be api/photo/photos/:id
  .post(employeePhotos)
```

On the frontend, the component from which the request is made has the following path :

```
http://localhost:3000/employeePhoto/5fc8a739a89f461274a6286f
```

I am using axios to POST the request like so:

```
axios.post(`api/photo/photos/${this.state._id}`,formData )
```

The challenge is that whenever i make a request to the endpoint 'api/photo/photos' i get a 404 response like so :

```
POST /employeePhoto/api/photo/photos/5fc8a739a89f461274a6286f 404 22.239 ms - 195
```

obviously this will not match the endpoint url hence the 404! How would i fix this mix up?

Comment: Your backend base url isn't the same as the frontend's. So Why not write the full url as the `axios.post` url?

Comment: I am confused when you said am using a different url in the frontend?!! the backend url is api/photo/photos and its the same thing i used in my axios post...what messes it up is the addition of employeePhoto/ path to it which is the path in the frontend where the request is made. i want a situation where it will just send '/api/photo/photos/userId, formData' without adding the employeePhoto/ path to it

Comment: What's your full backend url?

Comment: my full backend url is   'api/photo/photos/:id'

Comment: This isn't the full path. It should start with `http` etc.

Comment: Full : "http://localhost:5000/api/photo/photos/:id "  this path works perfectly with POSTMAN

Comment: Also note that am making use of proxy, I don't have to type http://localhost:5000 in my axios request because I already declared it in my package.json proxy to be equal to http://localhost:5000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225618/discussion-between-8sins-and-galabra).

Answer (score 0):

It happens beacause your url in axios is relative, you use this:

```
axios.post(`api/photo/photos/${this.state._id}`,formData )
```

I would suggest tu put a "/" before the url:

```
axios.post(`/api/photo/photos/${this.state._id}`,formData )
```

When not starting the url with /, it will be relative to whatever your path is currently. I solved the same issue based in this concept, more information
[StackOverflow ReactJs...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433174/react-request-url-changes-itself-depending-on-the-location-of-the-call-both-a)