# React request URL changes itself, depending on the location of the call. (Both axios and fetch)

Tags: reactjs, axios

1. I sent Axios Request in the React Component as always and succeeded.

*server > routes > product.js*

```
router.post("/removeImages", auth, (req, res) => {

    req.body.images.map(imgPath => {
        fs.unlink(imgPath, (err)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('Image removed successfully');
        });
    });

});
```

*client > src > components > FileUpload.js*

```
import Axios from 'axios';
function FileUpload(props) {
  ...
  Axios.post('api/product/removeImages', { images: Images });
```

2. So, I copied the line(`Axios.post('api/product/removeImages', { images: Images });`) and used it in the child component. Then, the following error occurred:

> POST http://localhost:3000/product/api/product/removeImages 404 (Not Found)

3. I thought it was an Axios bug, so I changed it to a `fetch()`, but I got the same result (404 Not Found). I do not know how hard-coded URL can change depending on the component. Maybe it was a React bug?

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Comment: Where are you defining your base URL for axios? Post that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a starting / in the url. When not starting the url with /, it will be relative to whatever your path is currently.
Meaning if you're currently in `localhost:3000/products`, any requests to the relative path `api/products/removeImages` will resolve to `localhost:3000/products/api/products/removeImages`

A call to `/api/products/removeImages`, with the staring /, will only be relational to the base url, in this case `localhost:3000`, not the current path, thus result in `locahost:3000/api/products/removeImages`.

tl;dr: Add a prefixing / to your urls to resolve your relative path issue.

Additionally, as @ataravati mentioned in the comments, best practice is to also set a baseURL for axios.